# My own ’character varying‘ type field, why is it a ‘text’ type in the pgsql view?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want this field to be of type character varying, why pgsql view converts me to text

I tried to define myself as a character varying type, but in the view of pgsql, I still output a field of text type.

my original  code

```
(
CASE area
    WHEN '0'::text THEN 'jp'::character varying
    WHEN '1'::text THEN 'en'::character varying
    WHEN '3'::text THEN 'cn'::character varying
    ELSE area
END 
) area,
```

Compiled code in design view

```
CASE t.area
--  This is the compiled code in the view.
            WHEN '0'::text THEN ('jp'::character varying)::text
            WHEN '1'::text THEN ('en'::character varying)::text
            WHEN '3'::text THEN ('cn'::character varying)::text
            ELSE t.area
        END AS area,


-- i want area type is character varying
```

This is not the case in other views, and my other field strings do not appear to be converted to text, so I want to know why this problem occurs.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the complete `CREATE VIEW` statement that was used.

Comment: There is no practical difference whatsoever between `character  varying` and `text` In fact you don't need that cast at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  my view is connected to a bi platform, if it is a text type when filtering this field, it can only be filtered by regular expressions.

Comment: So that's a limitation of that BI platform? Because there is no such restriction in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Yep, because the BI platform is not maintained, so I need to solve this problem.